# How do I apply bootstrap tooltip css to only a particular element?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I want to create two elements with bootstrap tooltips: one aligned to the top left (tr), and one just at the top (img).

The elements are as follows:

```
<tr data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="title2">
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
<tr/>


<img src="link.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="title1"/>
```

The below will make it work, but it sets the tooltip to the "top left" for ALL tooltips. I just want it for the tr element:

```
.tooltip {
     left:20px !important;
}
```

I have tried using both below which don't work:

```
tr.tooltip {
     left:20px !important;
}

.tooltip tr {
     left:20px !important;
}
```